# initializing a 48bpp bitmap from a file in c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap

I write a 48bppRgb to a file but when I create a bitmap from this file it is 32bppArgb(object img2 has a property PixelFormat.32bppArgb).

Minimized example:

```
Bitmap img1 = new Bitmap(100, 100, PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb);
img1.Save("/img1.bmp");
Bitmap img2 = new Bitmap("/img1.bmp");
```

Why?

Comment: Check out my article on code project for some explanations and a workaround. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/482727/GDIplus-Deep-Color-Workaround

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than one problem.  You didn't save the image in the BMP format.  The default format for Image.Save(string) is PNG.  The PNG encoder built into GDI+ doesn't support 48bpp images.  Saving as a BMP requires specifying the image format:

```
        Bitmap img1 = new Bitmap(100, 100, PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb);
        img1.Save("c:/temp/img1.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

You'll however find that the BMP encoder doesn't support 48bpp images either, you'll get a 24bpp image when you load it back.  None of the codecs supports 48bpp.

There's lots of missing functionality in GDI+.  ImageFormat.Icon doesn't work for example, it actually saves a PNG.  And support for any of the Indexed pixels formats is quite poor.  If you need this kind of support then you'll need a professional imaging library.  LeadTools or ImageMagick are the usual choices.